# Where exactly is this cross in Hong Kong?

Tags: hong-kong, identify-this, religion

I was digging around for something and stumbled upon a video about Hong Kong that had footage presumably from the area. In it, there was a still with a cross with the characters 成了 (probably in reference to "it is finished"---one of the last words of Jesus of Nazareth) written right to left on it.

[image: White cross with Chinese characters]

Where is this from exactly?

From the geography, I can tell that this is on a hill. Moreover, it looks like there's a body of water separating the buildings in the background and the foreground objects. Unfortunately, I can think of several locations in Hong Kong that might fit such a general description. I also haven't had much success with Google, although I will try some different search terms later.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In addition to Mark Mayo's answer, the cross is located in the mountainside on Needle Hill. It takes 15-20 mins to walk from the Sha Tin Railway Station via the path through Pai Tau Tsuen. There is no direct public transport(note1) there and there are not many signs.

The camp is not open to public but you can join [their events](http://www.tfscc.org/en/).

---

PS1: The characters 成了 on the cross comes from *John 19:30*

> 耶穌嘗〔 原文作受〕了那醋、就說、**成了**．便低下頭、將靈魂交付神了。[(CUV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_Union_Version)
>
> When Jesus therefore had received the vinegar, he said, **It is finished**: and he bowed his head, and gave up the ghost.

Which means Jesus are put to death, which enable the reconciliation between God and his creation.

---

PS2: Not many people go there even for the locals. I have lived in Sha Tin for more than 20 years but have visited there once only.

---

PS3:If you have extra time, you can visit the Ten Thousand Buddhas Monastery nearby. It is a good place for photography and it is open to public.

---

Note1: There is a minibus 481B to the nearby resident building Peak One Podium from Tsuen Wan via Tai Wai but there is no signs neither.

Comment: I lived in 大圍 but I have never realized there's a huge cross up in the hills...

Comment: Accepting this for now since the additional info was helpful (for me specifically, seeing as I was luckily able to location the specific name via other means).

Answer (score 19):

[**Tao Fong Shan**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tao_Fong_Shan) would appear to be what you're after.

It's a 500m hill, in Sha Tin, where the Tao Fong Shan Christian Centre is located.

From the wiki:

> "A 12-metre-high cross, facing Sha Tin, is the hallmark of the Centre.
>   The cross is a popular among visitors and is a place for outside
>   gatherings and meetings."

It includes a photo that seems to pretty much exactly match where yours is taken from.

[image]

(taken from the linked wiki page)

And for location:

[Google Map of location](https://www.google.com.au/maps/place/Tao+Fong+Shan+Christian+Centre/@22.3841889,114.1821588,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x3c2baf7ebdfb5387)

and

[Google preview of cross at location](https://www.google.com.au/maps/place/Tao+Fong+Shan+Christian+Centre/@22.3841889,114.1821588,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1s-C6DlO3ZhyDg%2FURsyOwF_CFI%2FAAAAAAAAABA%2FGzFp4rCWMFE!2e4!3e12!6s%2F%2Flh4.googleusercontent.com%2F-C6DlO3ZhyDg%2FURsyOwF_CFI%2FAAAAAAAAABA%2FGzFp4rCWMFE%2Fs114-k-no%2F!7i1224!8i1632!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x3c2baf7ebdfb5387!6m1!1e1)

Comment: Yep, I decided to risk it (given my shoddy Chinese skills) and do a search in Chinese. The results ended up being surprisingly easy to navigate; the first thing that came up was a Chinese Wikipedia page (with an English version!) with similar images.

Comment: I love that their cross is made of brutalist 6 ? inch steel bar with a real bolted bridge-mount at the bottom!  Totally cool.